# In android Detect USB devices

Tags: android, usb

How does android detect USB devices and show the notifications? How does android handle this functionality and what is its AOSP code.

Answer (score 0):

When there is some energy change in the device, when there is not, I believe there is no way to see if the USB is plugged or not.

You should make BroadcastReceiver to see when there is an action of Usb Attached or Detached.

Comment: Hi Gregores, then how come android recognizes :)